# Node Js Web socket client stops listening

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

I have built websocket client in node js. I need to restart it after every 8-10 days. It suddenly stops listening to the websocket server. I have used the following lib for connection.

```
"ws": "^6.2.1"
```

I do restart connection and print logs in onclose and onerror listeners.

```
    this.connection.onerror = error => {
                rawDataStreamLog.info("Websocket ::: onerror " + JSON.stringify(error))
                this.restartConnection();
            };
 this.connection.onclose = () => {  
                rawDataStreamLog.info("Websocket ::: onclose") 
                this.restartConnection()
        };
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When "It suddenly stops" it should emit `error` and `close` events. Consider logging those events somewhere so you could diagnose the issue. Also you could implement reconnect logic on these events.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I do reconnect in case of error or close. But neither get log nor the server gets restart. This shows that onclose or onerror never happened.

Comment: You wrote "it suddenly stops listening to the websocket server." How do you know? Does your program stop receiving `message` events? If you set up a timeout function to monitor the websocket object by looking at it every so often, what do you see in the websocket's `state` and `bufferedAmount` properties.

Comment: I get continuous stream of data from websocket. As soon as I receive data in `this.connection.onmessage`  listener, I pass it to RabbitMQ queue. So from RabbitMQ dashboard I find that after every 8 to 10 days my client stops listening. Also I print log of each reading I get from `this.connection.onmessage` listener.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely your server initiated the disconnection. Or maybe something went wrong with the network connection.

It has been my experience that websocket client code for long-lived connections should detect and handle close events by reconnecting.  If things still fail after several attempts to reconnect you can investigate what's wrong at the server or in the network.

Does your server send [websocket ping (keepalive) message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections)s? If not, it should.

Comment: I edited my question to show that I have added "onerror" and "onclose" listeners of websocket, but seems none of them gets called in such case. Our websocket continuously emits data and never stops.